# please I am beginner in programming and I get null after reading a text file in java using FileInputStream

Tags: java, filereader

//Reading the text file
    try{
       File myFile = new      File("C:\Users\Dell\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test.txt").getAbsoluteFile();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();

```
    int bytes = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int len;

    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    bytes += len;
}

System.out.println("Transfer completed, " + bytes + " bytes sent");

out.flush();
connection.close();


    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi Chris, Welcome to SO. could you edit your post to show the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this. Your outputstream is not writing to anything.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class stack2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

                File myFile = new File("D:\\light.txt").getAbsoluteFile();
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");

                int bytes = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int len;

                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    bytes += len;
                }

                System.out.println("Transfer completed, " + bytes + " bytes sent");

                out.flush();



            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

    }

}
```